# Tag VLANs and add IP addresses to Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, ip, linux-networking, vlan

I've been told to tag VLANs and add IP addresses to a Linux server.
It's using `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

I've never tried this before.

There's multiple VLANs with different IP subnets, some VLANs has the same IP subnets announced.

The physical server has 2 ethernet in port 2 and 3, and both ethernet contains same VLANs.

My approach would be to add `ifcfg-eth1.101` for my first IP address with the following inside, for VLAN 101:

```
DEVICE=eth1.101
BOOTPROTO=static
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=23.543.11.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.255
USERCTL=no
NETWORK=23.543.11.1
VLAN=yes
```

... then run `ifup eth1.101` and `systemctl restart network.service`

Is this correct, and am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks correct to me, for any RedHat-like distribution that is not using `NetworkManager`.

If you have two NICs with same VLANs, you might want to first bond the ports together (i.e. bond `eth1` and `eth2` into `bond0`) and then hang the VLANs onto the bond (i.e. instead of `ifcfg-eth1.101` with `DEVICE=eth1.101` you would use `ifcfg-bond0.101` with `DEVICE=bond0.101` etc.)

When using bonding, remember to select `BONDING_OPTS="mode=active-backup"` bonding mode unless you have confirmed with your network administrators that the default `balance-rr` bonding mode (or any other bonding mode) can be used. With managed switches, `balance-rr` may cause "MAC address flapping" warnings in switches and/or routers, which may annoy the network admins. If MAC address hijacking protection is enabled on the switches, the use of `balance-rr` may look like a hijacking attempt and cause a false alarm.

If you need multiple IP addresses on top of a VLAN, the syntax for extra IPs is (for a bonded interface) filename `ifcfg-bond0.101` for the "main interface", `ifcfg-bond0.101:0` for the first extra IP address, and so on. The number after the full stop is the VLAN number, and the number after the colon is the index number for extra IPs.

The contents of the `ifcfg-bond0.101:0` file should be similar to when configuring just one IP address:

```
DEVICE=eth0.101:0
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=xx.xx.xx.xx
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
ONBOOT=yes
VLAN=yes
```

Note that configuring IP aliases on top of VLANs in this way is guaranteed to be supported only on RHEL/CentOS 5 and above; it may have been added in mid-4.x release cycle, but I'm not sure about that.

With older OS versions, you would have had to write a custom script to initialize the IP aliases manually with `ifconfig`, as the `initscripts` package in 4.x did not originally have the capability to handle such a combination.

Comment: Thank you - very helpful. If I have multiple IP-adresses on VLAN 101 (a /28 range), and would like to have ex. 2 interfaces; one with IP x.y.z.A and one with IP x.y.z.B.
Should I then create 2 ifcfg-bond.0.101.x files, each with their respective IP announced, or 1 file with the whole /28 subnet?

Comment: Like that, but use a colon instead of full stop with the index number for the extra IPs. I expanded my answer to include this information.

Comment: Thank you - most helpful. I've accepted the answer, and tried to bump up the votes, but was unable to.

Comment: Final question, should the netmask for each IP (:x file) match the total subnet? For /28 then 255.255.255.240?

Comment: In your case, yes. However, it is technically possible to have multiple separate subnets in a single VLAN (just like the same is possible in a physical network segment with no VLANs), but that would usually be considered a bad network design: just one subnet per VLAN is a much cleaner design. But if you had to do that, then each IP would get the appropriate netmask for its respective subnet.